# SSL Certificate is Untrusted how to fix it

Tags: security-certificate, user-agent

How can i fix the untrusted ? And why it appears ? What may cause this problem.This is in FF but in Chrome is red https with x marked on it.

Comment: Could you paste in the exact error or message you're asking about? There's going to be a big difference between being told your certificate is untrusted versus the document including mixed un/secure content as in @jflaflamme's response.

Answer (score 2):

If your SSL certificate is not expired, you may want to check if you have unsecure items on your secure page.

Exemple loading an external javascript via non-SSL uri (http://)

Comment: There is no javascript with http, but there is couple images like that, can this be the problem ?

Comment: Yes, if you have images that use http rather than https then browsers show to the users in various ways that not all the content is secure.

Comment: Yes i meant by "unsecure items" images, css, scripts, etc .. go on your web page, do a "view source" and CTRL+F and type http, you will quickly find the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you registered the ssl for www and your are serving up a non www version of your site or vice versa? Figure out which you are using and redirect the other using .htaccess (or whatever your server uses) to the secure prefix.